# indicate if an element can be found in another vector in R

Tags: r, vector, element

two vectors (a,b) of type integer. 'b' is smaller than 'a'.
I need a logical vector for 'a', indicating if a specific element of 'a' is part of 'b'.

Is there a economic solution similar to '%in%' (which can not serve here)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide some example data

Comment: Why does `%in%` not serve here? If it is because your data is "large-ish", then the only thing that could be faster than `%in%` is `match` (for which `%in%` is just a thin wrapper). Anything faster might need compiled code, and I'm still not convinced you'll do much (if any) better.

Comment: `intersect()` ??

Comment: intersection is not the goal. I know that all elements of 'b' are part of 'a', but I need a logical vector : a<-c(6,2,3,4,5,1), b<-c(1,2,3), goal: c[F,T,T,F,F,T]

Comment: The solution is literally `a %in% b`..

Comment: agree with @r2evans: voting to close as unclear until you can explain why `%in%` doesn't work for you ... in principle you could parallelize `%in%`, but it would be a lot of work

Comment: I'm looking at @TonyLadson's answer, and while I was about to downvote it (for over-complicating things), I got to thinking: is your aversion to `%in%` based on a request to *"find a different way to do the same thing"*? If so, try `sapply(a, function(z) any(z == b, na.rm = TRUE))` (there are less-inefficient, short-cutting ways to do this, too). Otherwise, you really need to get back with us on why `%in%` does not do what you say.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `%in%` you could try string matching

```
a<-c(6,2,3,4,5,1)
b<-c(1,2,3)

a %in% b

#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

stringr::str_detect(as.character(a), as.character(b))

# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: +1 for making me think about a different to look at the question (not because I think this is the best way to go :-)